# How do I Continue a batch file only if a process IS running

Tags: process, batch-file, for-loop, tasklist

I have successfully managed to hold a batch file until a process ends. But how do I hold a batch file until a process starts?

I am working using the following code:

```
@echo off

set process_1="calc.exe"
set process_2="mmc.exe"
set ignore_result=INFO:
set no_ignore=mmc.exe

:1
for /f "usebackq" %%M in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_1%"`) do if not %%M==%ignore_result% goto 1
:2
for /f "usebackq" %%N in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_2%"`) do if not %%N==%no_ignore% goto 2

echo Stuff finished.......
```

All I get when the program isn't running is "INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria"

Thanks in advance

S

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the err (2) to the stdout (1):

```
@echo off
```

set process_1="calc.exe"
set process_2="mmc.exe"
set ignore_result=INFO:
set no_ignore=mmc.exe

:1
for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%M in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_1%" 2^>^&1`) do if not %%M==%ignore_result% goto 1
:2
for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%N in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_2%" 2^>^&1`) do if not %%N==%no_ignore% goto 2

echo Stuff finished.......

You could also use a `sleep` function (look for the one with `ping` command).